# I Can't find DTMF Decoder HT9170B IC in Proteus

Tags: simulation

So I'm trying build a project that is based on the DTMF decoding IC.
Obviously I want to simulate my project first on Proteus.
Unfortunately, I can't find the DTMF IC mentioned above. Is there any library out there that I can use? or maybe a an equivalent element functionally?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I expect you could code up a model of the thing, I have to ask why anyone would bother simulating something like that?

In my experience simulations shine for little bits of analogue (Filters, control loops, thing like that where you want a quick bode plot to sanity check your calcs), and for complex digital where modelsim and friends rock (Also for some RF and SI issues if you have those tools), but I don't think it would have ever occurred to me to bother simulating something like a DTMF decoder that I was buying in as a chip.

We sometimes get students here convinced that simulating an entire board design is the common thing to do, it nearly never is and is something very seldom done outside a certain sort of academia.

Comment: Let's hope its not the "instructor" mandating this.  Simulation is indeed a useful tool - but it's saved for the situations where what is learned is likely to exceed the effort, such as complex logic design in an FPGA or especially ASIC, specific analog sub-circuits, or fiddly RF stuff where geometry matters as much as the lumped elements - each of those typically needing a different type of specialized simulator.

Comment: I totally agree with dan mills but and as chris has guessed, it's being mandated by my instructor.

Comment: Oh Ouch! Ask for your money back, all that writing a model of that chip would teach is how to write Proteus models and that program is basically never seen outside acidementia. I can think of FAR more valuable things to teach in the time that bashing out some fairly complex programming would take.

Answer (score 1):

probably there's not. It's a pretty common task for an engineer to generate IC symbols and footprints for their EDA software (in your case, Proteus).

It's less common to expect or make an electrical model for a DTMF chip. I'd argue that you probably can't without extensive measurements make one.

Also, are you *sure* you need to use that antique IC? Typically, the job of that is done with a cheap microcontroller and minimal digital signal processing in software.

Comment: Well, the thing is I'm not allowed to use a microcontroller for this project, and thus the need for that antique IC. Any idea?

Comment: yeah, use a microcontroller in the same package and add a sticker saying "HT9170IB" on top of it. For example, Arrow sells [PICs](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/pic16f1847-ip/microchip-technology?utm_campaign=octopart_2018&utm_currency=EUR&utm_keyword=PIC16F1847-I%2FP&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_content=inv_listing&utm_source=octopart) for <200ct with free shipping.